# How to sum column of type string in footer?

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

A.O.A,

I have a report that shows Overtime of an employee of a particular month.
I want to calculate the total number of overtime in footer

This is how i'm calculating overtime

- **"tout"** is EmployeeLeavingtime
- **"otLimint"** is the Timelimit (like if ShiftEndTime is 6:00PM then overtime will be 
  calculated if tout is > 6:30)
- **shiftendTime** is (6:00PM)

  ```
  string timeOut = r["TimeOut"].ToString();
  Time tOUT = new Time(timeOut);
  Time OtLimit = new Time(18, 30, 00);

  if (tOUT > OtLimit)
  {
      DateTime ShiftendTime = Convert.ToDateTime(r["ShiftEndTime"].ToString());
      DateTime Out          = Convert.ToDateTime(r["TimeOut"].ToString());
      TimeSpan span         = Out.Subtract(ShiftendTime);
      r["OTHrs"] = span.ToString().Replace("-","");
  }
  ```

im using

```
Sum(Fields!TotalLH.Value) in Report footer expression
```

but this is not showing Total at runtime